# C# Need help editing my line numbering code

Tags: c#, return, word-wrap, line-numbers

I got a code for line numbering, it works perfectly fine for numbering lines the regular way but I'm looking for something a little bit different. I want my code to only count line breaks when i press enter(the program receives an return keycode) and not then the textbox automatically cut the lines with word wrapping. This is the code i'm using right now:

```
//Instructions
    int maxLC = 1; //maxLineCount - should be public
    private void InstructionsSyncTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int linecount = InstructionsSyncTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(InstructionsSyncTextBox.TextLength) + 1;
        if (linecount != maxLC)
        {
            InstructionsLineNumberSyncTextBox.Clear();
            for (int i = 1; i < linecount + 1; i++)
            {
                InstructionsLineNumberSyncTextBox.AppendText(Convert.ToString(i) + "\n");
            }
            maxLC = linecount;
        }
    }
```

How i think i would be done easiest is by saving the line count every time someone presses enter to a list and also everytime someone presses enter it updates the line number texbox with every line number at positions said in list. But i have no idea how to detect when an return is removed. Anybody knows how to solve this?

Comment: Can't you just use a regex and search for all instances of \r ?

Answer (score 0):

Extremely basic example that counts the lines in your code you posted:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string stringFromTextBox = 
@"  int maxLC = 1; //maxLineCount - should be public
    private void InstructionsSyncTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int linecount = InstructionsSyncTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(InstructionsSyncTextBox.TextLength) + 1;
        if (linecount != maxLC)
        {
            InstructionsLineNumberSyncTextBox.Clear();
            for (int i = 1; i < linecount + 1; i++)
            {
                InstructionsLineNumberSyncTextBox.AppendText(Convert.ToString(i) + ""\n"");
            }
            maxLC = linecount;
        }
    }";
            Regex r = new Regex("\r", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            int lines = r.Matches(stringFromTextBox).Count;
            //You'll need to run this line every time the user presses a key

        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know if you just missread what i wrote or if you are trolling but that is in no way close to what i need help with. I need to edit the code to only count returns, not count the rows int he code i posted...

Comment: The code I posted does exactly that,  it counts all the returns in the string.  If you need to retain the location of each return,  the `MatchCollection` returned by `r.Matches` will contain that data also.  Other than that, you're going to have to clarify your question, because that is what you asked.